# Craft 2.6 Session Issues

Tags: cache, session, craft2

We are having issues staying logged in to Craft (2.6). There was a plugin error which is what we thought was causing the issues, so we removed the sprout SEO plugin. However the error still persists. We keep getting kicked out, and sometimes the words 'unkown error' pop up. We have not bee able to load any new content due to this.

Please may you assist us urgently.

Thanks you so much,
Ashton

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons (mostly environmental) why a person would be logged out from the CP discussed in these posts (along with fixes/workarounds):

[Craft constantly logging out from admin area](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/952/craft-constantly-logging-out-from-admin-area)

[Migrated Server, Now Getting Logged Out Constantly](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9628/migrated-server-now-getting-logged-out-constantly)

[Keep on getting logged out when deploying using Capistano](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17289/keep-on-getting-logged-out-when-deploying-using-capistano)

[Users are always logged out on front end](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22226/users-are-always-logged-out-on-front-end)

[Load Balancing Craft CMS - Admin gets logged out instantly](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/load-balancing-craft-cms-admin-gets-logged-out-instantly)

I'd start by reviewing those.

> and sometimes the words 'unknown error' pop up.

My hunch is it's related to your session issues, but you can check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder for the underlying error message.

Also related and may be helpful:

[The Case of the Missing PHP Session](https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-case-of-the-missing-php-session)